# Spring Integration - How to use SpEL to filter message on an annotation base?

Tags: java, filter, annotations, spring-integration, spring-el

I read the xml based configuration on Spring Integration reference page:

```
<filter expression="#jsonPath(payload,'$..book[2].isbn') matches '\d-\d{3}-\d{5}-\d'"/>
```

What is the annotation based equivalence of this? So that I can use SpEL as the logic to filter messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the Java DSL...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow filteringFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("someChannel")
            .filter("#jsonPath(...) matches ...")
            .channel("outChannel")
            .get();
}
```

or configure it with beans...

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "someChannel")
public MessageHandler filter() {
    MessageFilter filter = new MessageFilter(selector());
    filter.setOutputChannelName("outChannel");
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public MessageSelector selector() {
    return new ExpressionEvaluatingSelector("#jsonPath(...) matches ...");
}
```

Comment: In case of Java you could just use `@Filter` on the POJO method which calls `JsonPathUtils.evaluate()` directly and performs desired `matches()` on the result from jsonPath

Comment: Thanks. Pardon my ignorance, if choose bean configuration, what should I put in the jsonPath(...)? logically be the payload/header of message. Then does the filter get all messages or filtered messages(ideally latter) and be used as normal message handler?

Comment: The same as if you used XML but, as @ArtemBilan said, you can invoke `JsonPathUtils` directly from Java (and use a `Pattern` to match the result to some regex).